Veritcal Scrollbar and horizantol scroll bar not remove how to fix this
I am getting problem the vertical and horizantol scrollbar issue in my ios device safari browser i have tested on iphone 14 pro, iphone 14, iphone 13pro and also test on iphone 15 that all devices i am not getting scrollbar and another ios devices showing that both horizantol and vertical scrollbar how can i slove this.
this is my css i have used for that
